# iOS UIWebview facebook sharer.php catch share event

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-sharer

We use sharer.php in a UIWebview in our app, since it enables very easy sharing with customized title and text and thumbnail without having to go through the process of setting up (and maintaining!) a facebook application (and we'd like it to stay that way).

Only problem is, that we'd like to programmatically close the UIWebview once the user clicks the share button.

is there a way to get notified in the iOS app about the user clicking the share button?

Comment: Hi, can you provide any link for implementing this sharer in uiwebview ? I am looking for sharing a photo to facebook from native ios app through uiwebview. Sorry for using this thread for asking this.